# Angular2: JsonObject as @Input value

Tags: typescript, angular

Angular2: 2.0.0-beta8

I would like to customize a Directive. In order to achieve that I created an Object that contains all my custom parameters and I hoped to pass it on my template like this :

My directive used in a template:

```
<div my-directive="{param1: 46, param2: 48}"></div>
```

---

Input in my Directive:

```
@Input('my-directive')
public conf: Configuration;
```

---

Param Object definition:

```
export interface Configuration{param1;param2; ...}
```

---

Sadly, it doesn't work. Maybe cause of a Json parse ?

- How to get it works ?
- Should I have to create this "Param Object" on my component, and pass it to the template using a variable ?
- Is there a best practices ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to assign an object use the `[propName]="value"` syntax

```
[my-directive]="{param1: 46, param2: 48}"
```

This is standard attribute binding where Angular isn't involved.

```
<div my-directive="{param1: 46, param2: 48}"></div>
```

Attributes can only hold strings. `@Input()` reads the value from the attribute after it was stringifyied.

Hint: For input- , output-, and directive names `myDirective` is preferred over `my-directive`. Only element names use `my-element` for custom elements compatibility.

Comment: Ergh my bad!! Thanks.. (tks for the hint too !)

Comment: In above solution my-directive taking input as string, How to pass dynamic obj which is prepared inside component

Comment: @Runali The answer is especially about passing an object, not a string. Sorry, I don't know what you mean.